# Upgrade OS Bionic to Focal which includes Openstack and Ceph cluster

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, ceph, kolla-ansible

So i have openstack and ceph cluster with 3 controllers and 3 computes. This is the information about my cluster :

OS : ubuntu bionic
Openstack kolla-ansible : Ussuri 10.4.0
Ceph ceph-ansible : Octopus 15.2.17

My goal is i want to upgrade my openstack cluster to yoga so i have to upgrade os ubuntu to focal, which include upgrading ceph cluster. I have a plan looks like this :

1. Upgrade openstack ussuri to victoria
2. Upgrade OS Ubuntu Bionic to Focal
3. Upgrade Ceph octopus to pacific
4. dst until (ceph quincy and openstack yoga)

Are there steps i have to concern so there is minimal downtime in cluster openstack and ceph operations?

i have already try upgrade to focal but the ceph osd having a down time and the openstack operational cannot run, so i have to run "ansible-playbook hosts site.yml" for my ceph cluster back to normal.

Comment: We don't know anything about your ceph cluster so there's no way to tell what could have gone wrong. It's also not clear if you colocate ceph and openstack services on the same nodes or if you have dedicated ceph servers. What exactly did you try when upgrading ceph (step by step) and how did it fail? A lot more details are necessary here.